# jquery, button that sets a radio field before submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, radio-button

I was trying to have a submitting button to set a radio input field before submitting the form. It sets correctly the check on the radio btn, but when it submits the form, it doesn't take the value of the radio field.

Here is some code I am using:

```
    $('.groupAttributeBtn').click(function(){
$(this).closest('.radioContainer').find('.attribute_radio').prop("checked", true);
    getProductAttribute();

    });
```

And the HTML is made of rows of a table with N buttons

```
<tr class="radioContainer">
<td style="width:40%;">
<span>Package 2 kg</span>
<input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="weight" value="2" />
</td>
<td><span class="costoAttributo">23</span></td>
<td style="width:40%;text-align:right;">                                                        
<button type="submit" name="Submit" class="exclusive btn btn-outline-inverse groupAttributeBtn">
<span>Add to cart</span>
</button>
</td>
</tr>
```

Any suggestion? How can I have the radio correctly set and then the button submit THAT value?

**It now takes the previously selected one.**

---

**I should probably mention that I am operating on the product.tpl template page of a Prestashop installation.**

Comment: What is error ? Please see console of browser if there is any error ?

Comment: No error in console. It just performs the radio setting, but it doesn't submit the right value. It takes the previously selected one.

Comment: Where is submit code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" name="Submit" class="exclusive btn btn-outline-inverse groupAttributeBtn">
```

use button type instead of submit

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and then put a $("#myform").submit(); but it still doesn't take the right value. Any idea?

Comment: submit refreshes the entire page so value of controls get lost.